# Extract h1 text from div class with scrapy or selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using python along with scrapy and selenium.I want to extract the text from the h1 tag which is inside a div class.
For example:

```
<div class = "example">
 <h1>
    This is an example
 </h1>
</div>
```

This is my tried code:

```
for single_event in range(1,length_of_alllinks):
        source_link.append(alllinks[single_event])          
        driver.get(alllinks[single_event])
        s = Selector(response)      
        temp = s.xpath('//div[@class="example"]//@h1').extract()
        print temp          
        title.append(temp)
        print title
```

Each and every time I tried different methods I got an empty list.

Now, I want to extract "This is an example" i.e h1 text and store it or append it in a list i.e in my example title.
Like:
temp = ['This is an example']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For once, it seems that in your HTML the class attribute of the  is "example" but in your code you're looking for other class values; At least for XPath queries, keep in mind that you search by *exact* attribute value. You can use something like:

```
s.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "example")]')
```

To find an element that has the "example" class but may have additional classes. I'm not sure if this is a mistake or this is your actual code. In addition the fact that you have spaces in your HTML around the '=' sign of the class attribute may not be helping some parsers either.

Second, your query used in `s.xpath` seems wrong. Try something like this:

```
temp = s.xpath('//div[@class="example"]/h1').extract()
```

Its not clear from your code what `s` is, so I'm assuming the `extract()` method does what you think it does. Maybe a more clean code sample would help us help you.

Comment: Will try that out the second thing that you have mentioned. Also can you explain what is selector(response)? I saw it in a tutorial but they did not explained. The thing is every time a new page loads when the loop runs and I want the h1 text which is there in that div class. So what does Selector(response) represents? what does it return?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following to extract the intended text:

```
s.xpath('//div[@class="example"]/h1/text()').extract()
```